# SQL aggregate sum produces unexpected output

Tags: postgresql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I don't understand how `sum` works.

For a PostgreSQL table in dbeaver:

| a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

the query

```
select a, b, c, d, sum(c) as sum_c, sum(d) as sum_d from abc a group by a, b, c, d
```

produces

| a | b | c | d | sum_c | sum_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 2 |

and I don't understand why: I expected `sum_c` would be `18` in each row, which is the sum of values in `c`, and `sum_d` would be `11` for the same reason.

Why do `sum_c` and `sum_d` just copy the values from `c` and `d` in each row?

Comment: You `group by a, b, c, d`. This means that you get sums for each group of a, b, c, d.

Comment: @alekscooper as per your expectation the value of sum_c and sum_d would be same for all rows, is that actually what you want ?

Comment: @forpas How should I group to get the sum of the whole column, could you explain, please?

Comment: @HarshGundecha yes, in each row in sum_c and sum_d I would like to have the actual sum of all values in c and in d, respectively.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @forpas 
1 2 3 2 18 11, 1 2 4 3 18 11, etc.

Comment: @forpas more importantly, I want to understand how my query works. Since it's syntactically correct, it does something, but I don't understand why it does it this way.

Comment: The query may be syntactically correct and provide results but `group by` is not the way to do what you want. Check my answer and also for more info you can google "sql group by".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the result that you want with `group by`.
When you aggregate with `group by` you create groups for all the columns that are after `group by` and for each of these groups you get the aggregated results.
For your sample data, one group is `1,2,3,2` and for this combination of values you get the sum of `c` which is `3` since there is only 1 row with `c=3` in that group.

Use `SUM()` window function:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, 
       SUM(c) OVER () sum_c, 
       SUM(d) OVER () sum_d 
FROM abc
```